# Can transactions sent later have a lower block number?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, ether

I apologize in advance if my question is stupid.

> What I'm curious about is that transactions sent first must be recorded in the preceding **block number**?

As far as I know, just because you enter the pending `state` first does not mean you will be in the commit state first.

> If so, can transactions sent later have a lower block number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, a transaction you send after another can be included before the earlier one if you set a higher gas fee to it and it’s picked up by a miner before the earlier one.

A transaction sent doesn’t mean it was added to a block and processed yet.

Edit: there is actually two cases here:

1. both transaction have the same nonce, and the first one included in a block will make the other one invalid since a nonce can only be used once
2. the transactions have following nonce, and the higher nonce transaction will only be processed once the lower nonce transaction is processed.

Comment: You might want to add that the previous transaction will get reverted then as it uses the same nonce

Comment: You are correct, I edited my answer

Comment: Thanks for your help! After listening to you and thinking about it, if I want to save the cursor while processing the events that happened in the contract in order, I think I can use Nonce. Is that what I understand?